# Sending e-mail through libCurl (C)

Tags: c, email, libcurl

I'm trying to send e-mail through libCurl, but i can't seem to make it work:

My code is hanging at the end of the sending sequence as follows:

```
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
[New Thread 0x7ffff2bf7700 (LWP 27664)]
[Thread 0x7ffff2bf7700 (LWP 27664) exited]
*   Trying 2a00:f60::1:22...
* Connected to smtp.xxxxx.com (2a00:f60::1:22) port 25 (#0)
< 220 net3-nl-proxy-12.xxxxx.net ESMTP Postfix
> EHLO barrybackup
< 250-net3-nl-proxy-12.xxxxx.net
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-SIZE 262144000
< 250-ETRN
< 250-STARTTLS
< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250 DSN
> STARTTLS
< 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=Hosted by xxxxx Services bv; OU=PositiveSSL; CN=smtp.xxxxx.com
*    start date: 2015-06-23 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-06-27 23:59:59 GMT
*    issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> EHLO barrybackup
< 250-net3-nl-proxy-12.xxxxx.net
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-SIZE 262144000
< 250-ETRN
< 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250 DSN
> AUTH LOGIN
< 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
> aW5mb0BjdW1idWNrZXQubmw=
< 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
> Rmw0cGRyMGwyMDEy
< 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
> MAIL FROM:<info@xxx.com>
< 250 2.1.0 Ok
> RCPT TO:<info@xx-xx.nl>
< 250 2.1.5 Ok
> DATA
< 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
```

I can't seem to find out any clues and completly stuck.

Code:

```
typedef struct {
    const char* toEmail;
    const char* toName;
    const char* fromEmail;
    const char* fromName;
    const char** subject;
    const char** email;
    size_t pos;
} EmailData;

EmailData* initEmailData(EmailData* data, const char* toEmail,const char* toName,const char* fromEmail, const char* fromName, const char* subject, const char* body) {

    data->toEmail   = toEmail;
    data->toName    = toName;
    data->fromEmail = fromEmail;
    data->fromName  = fromName;


    // the added numbers to the length of the string are the pre-computed
    // lengths of the strings to be concatenated + 1 (for termination char)
    size_t htmlSize = strlen(body) + 24;
    char *html = malloc(htmlSize);
    snprintf(html, htmlSize, "%s%s", body, "\r\n");    

    size_t headerSize = strlen(subject) + 14;
    char *header = malloc(1);
    snprintf(header, headerSize, "%s%s%s", "Subject: ", subject, "\r\n");

    size_t receiverSize = strlen(toName)+strlen(toEmail) + 30;
    char *receiver = malloc(receiverSize);
    snprintf(receiver, receiverSize, "%s%s (%s)%s", "To: ", toEmail, toName, "\r\n");

    size_t senderSize = strlen(fromEmail) + strlen(fromName) + 30;
    char *sender = malloc(senderSize);
    snprintf(sender, senderSize, "%s%s (%s)%s", "From: ", fromEmail, fromName, "\r\n");

    size_t timeSize = 40;
    char* timeString = malloc(timeSize);
    time_t rawtime = 0;
    time(&rawtime);
    struct tm *timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    strftime (timeString, timeSize, "Date: %a, %d %b %Y %T %z\r\n", timeinfo);

    const char **payload = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 18);
    const char* setup[] =
    {
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n",
        timeString,
        receiver,
        sender,
        header,
        // describe the data contained in the body
        // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-5.1.1
        "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=border\r\n",
        // empty line to divide headers from body, see RFC5322
        "\r\n",
        // all boundaries must start with two hyphens
        "--border\r\n",
        // let recipient interpret displaying text, send plain text & HTML
        // specify the plain text encoding
        "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n",
        "\r\n",
        body,
        "\r\n",
        "--border\r\n",
        // specify the HTML encoding
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n",
        "\r\n",
        html,
        "\r\n",
        // final boundary ends with two hyphens as well
        "--border--\r\n",
        NULL
    };

    int i;
    for (i = 0; setup[i]; i++) {
        *(payload + i) = setup[i];
    }

    data->email = payload;
    data->pos = 0;
    return data;
}

size_t readCallback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    if((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size * nmemb) < 1)) return 0;

    EmailData *upload = (EmailData*) userp;
    const char *email = upload->email[upload->pos];

    if(email)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(email);
        if (len > size * nmemb) return CURL_READFUNC_ABORT;
        memcpy(ptr, email, len);
        upload->pos++;
        return len;
    }
    return 0;
}


int sendMailUsingCurl(char* toEmail, char* toName,char* fromEmail, char* fromName, char* subject,char* body) {


    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
    struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;
    EmailData data = {0};
    initEmailData(&data,toEmail,toName,fromEmail,fromName,subject,body);

    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)
    {
        // set username and password
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "xxxx@xx.xx");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "xxxxx");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtp://smtp.x.com:25/");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, (long)CURLUSESSL_ALL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, fromEmail);

        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, toEmail);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, readCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
        // useful for debugging encryped traffic
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        // send the message
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK) fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        curl_slist_free_all(recipients);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Unfortunatly, GDb is not returning anything and i don't get code errors, but still it's not sending anything.

Every clue would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing this line: `354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>`.

A `"\r\n.\r\n"` sequence indicates the end of the e-mail data.  So right after the

```
"--border--\r\n",
```

add

```
".\r\n",
```

Next the server should then response with a `250 OK`.  After the `250 OK` you should respond with `QUIT`.  Perhaps curl will correctly take care of the `250 OK/QUIT` interaction for you.